# TeamCity, How to include original nunit, dotcover, fxcop xml log files in the artifact

Tags: teamcity

im setting up different build steps for each of the tasks, Nunit/dotcover, fxcop.

is it possible to include the original xml files produced by nunit, dotcover, and fxcop as the build artifacts?

currently the artifacts are the generated html file from the original xml files.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the orginal xml files from nunit,dotcover and fxcop are located within your Build Folder you will be enter the path to them to include them as artifacts.